# Prove set of free generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Prove that if $X=\{x,y \}$ is a set of free generators then set $X^{-1} = \{x^{-1}, y^{-1} \}$ is also a set of free generators.

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Notice that because a generator forms a group, $x^{-1},y^{-1}\in <x,y>$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: It will be enough? But how can I prove that it generate the same group?

Comment: @json Can you show that e.g. $x\in\langle x^{-1}\rangle$?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it]

Comment: Hint: what is $(x^{-1})^{-1}$?

Comment: it is x. So is it a symmetric case?